# Page gets cut in half on print

Tags: php, html, css, printing

I created a ticket system and would like to print out all open tickets in my database.

I'm doing this by creating a print button like this:

```
<button onclick="printContent('print')" class="print-btn">Print All Tickets</button>
```

This pulls information from a `display: none` div I call `<div id="print">`

Upon pressing the print button it grabs all the tickets from my table and prints them out.
This is works great for printing a single ticket, but if I want to print all the Open tickets, the tickets get cut in half on some page breaks.

I did a  little research and added.

```
@media print  
{
    div{
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
```

to my css style file, but didn't help.

My tickets still look like this when printing.

[image]

I was also wondering if its possible to convert whats pictured in my question to a .pdf then print. My theory behind this is that if converted to a .pdf, it would avoid the page breaks and print correctly. I

If anyone has a solution please let me know, I would appreciate it.

Comment: printing html from a browser has always been a total crapshoot. go with PDFs. then you have total control over page layouts and page breaks.

Comment: @MarcB could you give me a little guidance on how to create the pdf?

Comment: there's multiple php libraries for creating pdfs server-side. we're not here to recommend for/against or find a library for you.